# Numpy - how interp function works?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to understand how numpy.interp function works. This function has a couple of parameters which are vague to me, like: xp, fp, left and right.

I saw an example of this function as below:

`X` is a numpy ndarray and `y` is one-dimensional array:

```
X = np.interp(X, (X.min(), X.max()), (0, 10))
y = np.interp(y, (y.min(), y.max()), (30000, 100000))
```

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: I think the documentation is pretty good. Did you  go through https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html. If there is something not clear in the explanation given there, do write back.

Comment: I don't understand what are xp,fp, and right and left. I read the documentation, but I don't understand it still.

Answer (score 4):

- `x` are the points which are not in `xp` but you want their `y` values i.e. points where you want to perform interpolation
- `xp` and `yp` are the main inputs based on which 1D interpolation works (these are the discrete data points through which you want to interpolate)
- `left` and `right` handle the edge case scenarios when `x` is out of the closed interval range of `[xp_minimum, xp_maximum]` i.e. the output values to generate incase of **extrapolation**